# How to extract part of a file saved in HDFS and save it as csv?

Tags: pyspark, hdfs

My Device file is saved in HDFS and I need to take 100 rows from that saved file 
and save as csv in my local filesystem.

I have tried this command:

```
hdfs dfs -text /path to hdfs/Device/* > DEvice.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 hdfs dfs -text /path to hdfs/Device/* | head -100 > DEvice.csv
```

This will get the first 100 lines, uncompressed from the Hadoop file and store them to the csv file in your local filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

```
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /path_to_hdfs/Device/* path_to_local_file.csv | head -100
```

Comment: Please mark as 'answer' if it solved your problem :)